# programmatically use git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase

I wrote a node module that uses git to make a bunch of commits from time to time. Considering the commits are better if grouped into one single commit, I'd like to use "git rebase -i" to squash them into one.

However squashing is only possible in interactive mode, which means I need to manually edit the lines in the editor that pops up when "git rebase -i" is called. I would like to know if it is possible to do this process programatically? So for example when the user calls "save" function my module would make a bunch of commits, and then automatically squash them together.

**UPDATE**

To be more precise of what I'm doing, when the "save" function is called, it is passed a bunch of commits to be "publish". My module will then cherry pick those commits and put them into the "publish" branch. This is a single "publish" action, but it generates a bunch of commits on the "publish" branch. What I wanna do is to squash the commits on the publish, so when I do "git log" all I see is "publish version 1", "publish version 2" etc, instead of 5 or 10 commits per publish action.

Comment: Why don't you just make these "better if grouped" commits with `git commit --amend`?

Comment: @meagar Thanks for the reply, but these commits are actually cherry-picked into another branch, there is no way to know ahead of time which commits will be grouped until they are cherry-picked by the process.

Comment: Why not just script that actions with `reset` and `commit`?

Comment: @CharlesBailey But how do I do that with reset and commit?

Comment: If you have a second branch onto which these commits are moved, you could then merge that branch back in with a `git merge --squash`.

Comment: and rebase also has a `--squash` switch afaik

Comment: Just use what ever parameters make sense. I don't know what logic you are using to cherry-pick / group your commits so it's hard to give any specific help.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thanks for your comment, I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your update to your question, one of the two options below may work, depending on your usage:

---

The first (and simpler) case is where your unpublished work is always a single sequence of commits, and the published work is on the same branch, but a bit further behind:

- You have an `unpublished` branch and a `published` branch. The latter is contained within the former (i.e. some number of commits behind).
- The save action means that a hash `abcdef` from `unpublished` should now be the HEAD of `published`.
- It performs `git checkout published && git merge --ff-only abcdef`.
- This causes `published` to fast-forward to that commit.

---

The second is where the commits that can be published are not necessarily a linear sequence. This becomes a little more complicated as if you reorder commits, you may have to resolve conflicts that arise. I would solve that in the following way:

- Assume again that there are `unpublished` and `published` branches.
- The save action comprises some hashes from `unpublished`.
- It should create a new, temporary branch like `publish-2013-04-15-001` from the current `published` branch (the name of the new branch is largely irrelevant, as long as it's unique/new).
- Perform `git cherry-pick <hash>` for each hash that should be saved. (If there are multiple commits, this is where you could get conflicts and may need to resolve them somehow.)
- Once done, check out `published` branch.
- Perform `git merge --squash -m 'Publish version <n>' publish-2013-04-15-001`.
- (Optional) delete the temporary branch.

Since the second option introduces more complication, there are other options that you might want to consider to make it easier to debug the published process:

- Should I keep the temporary branches around for tracking/logging?
- Could the individual commits be kept separate on the merged branch (leave out `--squash`)?
- If so, you could identify the save by forcing a merge commit (`--no-ff`).

**EDIT**: Here's an example using `--no-ff`. Each version `$N` does the following:

```
git checkout -b publish-$N published
# cherry-pick commits
git checkout published && git merge --no-ff publish-$N -m "Publish version $N"
```

[image: example tig graph]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the temporary branch is the approach closest to what I want, as the commits I want to make are no necessarily a linear sequence (conflicts can be easily resolved due to the nature of my project). However I don't quite understand your updated comment: what do you mean by "you could identify the save by forcing a merge commit --no-ff"?

Comment: @Xavier_Ex I've updated the question with an example topology that would result from that option.

Comment: thanks for the attached img, but what's the difference between --squash and --no-ff in this case? To my understanding, --squash will squash all the commits into one and create a SINGLE merge commit, while --no-ff will always create a SINGLE merge commit. I can't see the difference...?

Comment: `--squash` would simply result in a number of non-merge commits with message "Published version $N". There would be no merges and no way to separate the individual commits (i.e. unsquash) afterwards. The `--no-ff` scenario leaves the original commits and messages intact, and groups them together with a merge commit.

Comment: Does it mean by using --squash you can still see multiple commits in history but they are somehow tied up? Sorry I might be a bit confused here... Could you please tell me what the definition is for "merge commit"?

Comment: Have a look at [this example image](http://nvie.com/img/2010/01/merge-without-ff.png) to explain what `--no-ff` does. A merge commit may introduce no code changes itself, but simply identifies that it has more than 1 parent (i.e. merging `A` into `B` has both `A` and `B` as its parent commits). Squash takes all of the individual commits and combines the changes into one changeset.

Comment: Thanks, I tried out both --squash and --no-ff and found that when I use git log, --squash will show all my commits somehow, but --no-ff will only show one commit. Which I'm certain --no-ff is my choice here.